# Finding shortest paths in directed graphs

Tags: c++, algorithm, pathfinding, breadth-first-search, framework

I have very little experience in programming with C++ and the following small "program" is the 2nd one I have ever written in that language. I am most interested in comments regarding naming conventions and the way the code is modularized. Also, can you tell whether the code sticks to idiomatic use of the language?

Here what I have so far:

**directed_graph_node.h**:

```
#ifndef DIRECTED_GRAPH_NODE_H
#define DIRECTED_GRAPH_NODE_H

#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

/*******************************************************************************
* This class implements a node in directed graphs. The adjacency list          *
* invariant is that if there is a directed edge from u to v, u.m_out has a     *
* pointer to v, and v.m_in has a pointer to u.                                 *
*******************************************************************************/
class DirectedGraphNode {
public:
    DirectedGraphNode(const std::string name);
    void add_child(DirectedGraphNode& child);
    bool has_child(DirectedGraphNode& query);
    void remove_child(DirectedGraphNode& child);

    // Child iterators.
    std::unordered_set<DirectedGraphNode*>::const_iterator begin();
    std::unordered_set<DirectedGraphNode*>::const_iterator end();

    bool operator==(const DirectedGraphNode& other) const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, 
                                    const DirectedGraphNode& node);

    // Forward declaration.
    class ParentIteratorProxy;

    ParentIteratorProxy parents();

    class ParentIteratorProxy {
    public:
        ParentIteratorProxy(const DirectedGraphNode* owner);
        std::unordered_set<DirectedGraphNode*>::const_iterator begin();
        std::unordered_set<DirectedGraphNode*>::const_iterator end();

    private:
        const DirectedGraphNode* mp_owner;
    };

private:
    std::string m_name;
    std::unordered_set<DirectedGraphNode*> m_in;
    std::unordered_set<DirectedGraphNode*> m_out;
};

#endif  // DIRECTED_GRAPH_NODE_H
```

**directed_graph_node.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <unordered_set>

#include "directed_graph_node.h"

/*******************************************************************************
* Constructs a new DirectedGraphNode with the given name.                      *
*******************************************************************************/
DirectedGraphNode::DirectedGraphNode(const std::string name) {
    m_name = name;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Creates a directed edge from this node to node 'child'.                      *
*******************************************************************************/ 
void DirectedGraphNode::add_child(DirectedGraphNode& child) {
    m_out.insert(&child);
    child.m_in.insert(this);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Queries whether there is an arc (this, query).                               *
*******************************************************************************/
bool DirectedGraphNode::has_child(DirectedGraphNode& query) {
    if (m_out.find(&query) == m_out.end()) {
        if (query.m_in.find(this) != query.m_in.end()) {
            // The adjacency list invariant is broken. See the header.
            throw std::runtime_error("Adjacency list invariant broken. 1/2.");
        }

        return false;
    } else if (query.m_in.find(this) == query.m_in.end()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Adjacency list invariant broken. 2/2.");
    }

    return true;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Removes the edge (this, child).                                              *
*******************************************************************************/
void DirectedGraphNode::remove_child(DirectedGraphNode& child) {
    m_out.erase(&child);
    child.m_in.erase(this);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Compares by name this node to 'other'.                                       *
*******************************************************************************/
bool DirectedGraphNode::operator ==(const DirectedGraphNode& other) const {
    return this->m_name.compare(other.m_name) == 0;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns a const iterator to a child node of this node.                       *
*******************************************************************************/
std::unordered_set<DirectedGraphNode*>::const_iterator 
DirectedGraphNode::begin() {
    return m_out.begin();
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns a const iterator to the end of child list.                           *
*******************************************************************************/
std::unordered_set<DirectedGraphNode*>::const_iterator
DirectedGraphNode::end() {
    return m_out.end();
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns a proxy iterator over a node's parent nodes.                         *
*******************************************************************************/
DirectedGraphNode::ParentIteratorProxy
                 ::ParentIteratorProxy(const DirectedGraphNode* p_owner) : 
                 mp_owner(p_owner) {}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the first parent node in the parent list of the owner node.          *
*******************************************************************************/
std::unordered_set<DirectedGraphNode*>::const_iterator
DirectedGraphNode::ParentIteratorProxy::begin() {
    return mp_owner->m_in.begin();
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns an iterator pointing to the end of owner node's parent list.         *
*******************************************************************************/
std::unordered_set<DirectedGraphNode*>::const_iterator
DirectedGraphNode::ParentIteratorProxy::end() {
    return mp_owner->m_in.end();
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns an iterator over owner node's parent list.                           *
*******************************************************************************/
DirectedGraphNode::ParentIteratorProxy DirectedGraphNode::parents() {
    return ParentIteratorProxy(this);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Neatly prints a node.                                                        *
*******************************************************************************/
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DirectedGraphNode& node) {
    return os << "[DirectedGraphNode " << node.m_name << "]";
}
```

**path_finder.h**:

```
#ifndef PATHFINDER_H
#define PATHFINDER_H

#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

#include "directed_graph_node.h"

using std::unordered_map;
using std::vector;

class PathFinder {
public:
    virtual std::vector<DirectedGraphNode*>* 
        search(DirectedGraphNode& source,
               DirectedGraphNode& target) = 0;

    vector<DirectedGraphNode*>* 
        construct_path(DirectedGraphNode* touch,
                       unordered_map<DirectedGraphNode*,
                                     DirectedGraphNode*>* p_parents_f,
                       unordered_map<DirectedGraphNode*,
                                     DirectedGraphNode*>* p_parents_b) {
        vector<DirectedGraphNode*>* p_path = new vector<DirectedGraphNode*>;
        DirectedGraphNode* u = const_cast<DirectedGraphNode*>(touch);

        while (u) {
            p_path->push_back(u);
            u = (*p_parents_f)[u];
        }

        std::reverse(p_path->begin(), p_path->end());

        if (p_parents_b) {
            u = (*p_parents_b)[touch];
            while (u) {
                p_path->push_back(u);
                u = (*p_parents_b)[u];
            }
        }

        return p_path;
    }
};

#endif // PATHFINDER_H
```

**bfs_path_finder.h**:

```
#ifndef BFS_PATH_FINDER_H
#define BFS_PATH_FINDER_H

#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

#include "directed_graph_node.h"
#include "path_finder.h"

/*******************************************************************************
* Implements a path finder using breadth-first search in unweighted digraphs.  *
*******************************************************************************/
class BFSPathFinder : public PathFinder {
public:
    std::vector<DirectedGraphNode*>* search(DirectedGraphNode& source,
                                            DirectedGraphNode& target) {
        m_queue.clear();
        m_parent_map.clear();

        // Initialize the state.
        m_queue.push_back(&source);
        m_parent_map[&source] = nullptr;

        while (!m_queue.empty()) {
            DirectedGraphNode* p_current = m_queue.front();

            if (*p_current == target) {
                // Reached the target.
                return construct_path(p_current, &m_parent_map, nullptr);
            }

            m_queue.pop_front();

            for (auto p_child : *p_current) {
                if (m_parent_map.find(p_child) == m_parent_map.end()) {
                    m_parent_map.insert({p_child, p_current});
                    m_queue.push_back(p_child);
                }
            }
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

private:
    std::deque<DirectedGraphNode*> m_queue;
    std::unordered_map<DirectedGraphNode*, 
                       DirectedGraphNode*> m_parent_map;
};

#endif // BFS_PATH_FINDER_H
```

**bibfs_path_finder.h**:

```
#ifndef BIBFS_PATH_FINDER_H
#define BIBFS_PATH_FINDER_H

#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

#include "directed_graph_node.h"
#include "path_finder.h"

/*******************************************************************************
* Implements a path finder using bidirectional breadth-first search for        *
* unweighted digraphs.                                                         *
*******************************************************************************/
class BidirectionalBFSPathFinder : public PathFinder {
public:
    std::vector<DirectedGraphNode*>* search(DirectedGraphNode& source,
                                            DirectedGraphNode& target) {
        m_queue1.clear();
        m_queue2.clear();
        m_parent_map1.clear();
        m_parent_map2.clear();
        m_distance_map1.clear();
        m_distance_map2.clear();

        // Initialize the state.
        m_queue1.push_back(&source);
        m_queue2.push_back(&target);
        m_parent_map1[&source] = nullptr;
        m_parent_map2[&target] = nullptr;
        m_distance_map1[&source] = 0;
        m_distance_map2[&target] = 0;

        // A node where the two search frontiers "meet".
        DirectedGraphNode* p_touch = nullptr;
        // The best known cost of a shortest path.
        size_t best_cost = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max();

        while (m_queue1.size() > 0 && m_queue2.size() > 0) {
            if (p_touch != nullptr
                    && m_distance_map1[m_queue1.front()] 
                     + m_distance_map2[m_queue2.front()] >= best_cost) {
                // Termination condition met.
                return construct_path(p_touch,
                                      &m_parent_map1,
                                      &m_parent_map2);
            }

            // A trivial load balancing.
            if (m_queue1.size() < m_queue2.size()) {
                // Once here, expand the forward search frontier.
                DirectedGraphNode* p_current = m_queue1.front();

                if (m_parent_map2.find(p_current) != m_parent_map2.end()) {
                    // Here, update to the shortest path is possible.
                    const size_t tmp = m_distance_map1[p_current] +
                                       m_distance_map2[p_current];

                    if (best_cost > tmp) {
                        // Update the current best touch node.
                        best_cost = tmp;
                        p_touch = p_current;
                    }
                }

                m_queue1.pop_front();

                // Expand the forward search frontier.
                for (auto p_child : *p_current) {
                    if (m_parent_map1.find(p_child) == m_parent_map1.end()) {
                        m_parent_map1.insert({p_child, p_current});
                        m_distance_map1.insert({
                            p_child, 
                            m_distance_map1[p_current] + 1
                        });
                        m_queue1.push_back(p_child);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Once here, expand the backward search frontier.
                DirectedGraphNode* p_current = m_queue2.front();

                if (m_parent_map1.find(p_current) != m_parent_map1.end()) {
                    // Here, update to the shortest path is possible.
                    const size_t tmp = m_distance_map1[p_current] +
                                       m_distance_map2[p_current];

                    if (best_cost > tmp) {
                        // Update the current best touch node.
                        best_cost = tmp;
                        p_touch = p_current;
                    }
                }

                m_queue2.pop_front();

                // Expand the backward search.
                for (auto p_parent : p_current->parents()) {
                    if (m_parent_map2.find(p_parent) == m_parent_map2.end()) {
                        m_parent_map2.insert({p_parent, p_current});
                        m_distance_map2.insert({
                            p_parent,
                            m_distance_map2[p_current] + 1
                        });
                        m_queue2.push_back(p_parent);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

private:
    std::deque<DirectedGraphNode*> m_queue1;
    std::deque<DirectedGraphNode*> m_queue2;
    std::unordered_map<DirectedGraphNode*, 
                       DirectedGraphNode*> m_parent_map1;
    std::unordered_map<DirectedGraphNode*,
                       DirectedGraphNode*> m_parent_map2;
    std::unordered_map<DirectedGraphNode*,
                       size_t> m_distance_map1;
    std::unordered_map<DirectedGraphNode*,
                       size_t> m_distance_map2;
};

#endif  // BIBFS_PATH_FINDER_H
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is quite a bit of code here, so consequently my review is not going to be the definitive. The things that most caught my attention:

### In all classes:

You are using very long names everywhere like in

```
std::unordered_set<DirectedGraphNode*>::const_iterator
```

It is very easy to mistype such names and get a torrent of template erros from the compiler that can be a pain to read and figure out. Replace all those with `using` aliases. E.g.:

```
using DirectedGraphNodeSet     = std::unordered_set<DirectedGraphNode*>;
using DirectedGraphNodeSetIter = DirectedGraphNodeSet::const_iterator;
```

### directed_graph_node.cpp:

Make sure to always initialize data in the constructor by calling the constructors of the sub-objects:

```
DirectedGraphNode::DirectedGraphNode(std::string name)
    : m_name(std::move(name)) {
}
```

Also, in this case `name` should not be const. If it is const, you cannot move it, resulting in an extra unnecessary copy of the string.

Speaking of [`move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move), your classes don't provide move operator and constructor. Not sure if those would apply, but if you are not familiar with the concept yet (C++11), take a look at the previous link and also on [The rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

---

```
throw std::runtime_error("Adjacency list invariant broken. 1/2.");
```

That error message is not very helpful. Better to name which invariant was broken instead of numbering it.

---

```
bool DirectedGraphNode::operator ==(const DirectedGraphNode& other) const {
    return this->m_name.compare(other.m_name) == 0;
}
```

Using the `==` operator would be more straightforward in this case:

```
bool DirectedGraphNode::operator ==(const DirectedGraphNode& other) const {
    return this->m_name == other.m_name;
}
```

### path_finder.h:

One thing that bothers me in here is this `vector<DirectedGraphNode*>*`. You return that pointer, which is allocated with `new`, but it is not clear for the caller who owns it. There is potential for a memory leak there. I think a [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) would be in order.

---

This is also not cool:

```
using std::unordered_map;
using std::vector;
```

In the global namespace, they will leak to any other file that includes `path_finder.h`. Replace those with a `using` alias inside the class.

---

Otherwise, the code looks nice. You have used modern C++ throughout. I hope you also get more reviews on the algorithms an architecture.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you can use C++11.

- Your parameter passing is a bit off. There are a lot of options, these are the most common ones:

  - `const &T`, meaning the function should use the objects as it is or make a copy.
  - `&&T` or `unique_ptr<T>` (or less commonly just the value), meaning the function is given an object and can do whatever it wants with it, including taking ownership, modifying and throwing it away.

  `DirectedGraphNode(const std::string name)` takes `name` by const value, which creates a copy of the parameter passed which then cannot be modified. In the implementation you then make another copy. The canonical way is to pass `const std::string &name`. This is not just crazy C++ efficiency addiction, it is about self documenting code. The meanings above are well understood whereas your version has people wondering how to use that strange looking code correctly.

  Now, if you do want to get into crazy C++ efficiency addiction you can provide an additional overload `DirectedGraphNode(std::string &&name) : m_name(std::move(name)){}`. This provides the option to hand over an existing string without copying it. Not that this will give you much efficiency, but sometimes this matters. You may be thinking about passing `string &name`, because that eliminates the copy too, just like you did in `add_child`, `has_child` and `remove_child`. The problem with `string &name` is that it is shared with other code and changing `name` may have funny side effects. With `string &&name` you get your personal string that will not be used outside this function anymore because it is about to be destroyed, meaning you do not need to worry about other code.
- You can compare strings using `==`. Instead of

  ```
  bool DirectedGraphNode::operator ==(const DirectedGraphNode& other) const {
      return this->m_name.compare(other.m_name) == 0;
  }
  ```

  you can write

  ```
  bool DirectedGraphNode::operator ==(const DirectedGraphNode& other) const {
      return m_name == other.m_name;
  }
  ```

  I was not aware `std::string` has a member function `compare`. You may have been thinking about C's *"never compare strings using `==`"*. That is good advice for `char *`, but not necessary for `std::string`.
- Avoid using naked `new`. Manually managing memory is difficult, boring and error prone. C++ gives you the tools to handle that whole class of problems automatically and efficiently and the cases where you need to intervene are rare.

  ```
  vector<DirectedGraphNode*>* construct_path(...) {
      vector<DirectedGraphNode*>* p_path = new vector<DirectedGraphNode*>;
      ...
      return p_path;
  }
  ```

  If you just call `construct_path(...);` you already have a memory leak. It is difficult to know that you have to call `delete` on that pointer. Fortunately the solution is really easy:

  ```
  vector<DirectedGraphNode*> construct_path(...) {
      vector<DirectedGraphNode*> p_path;
      ...
      return p_path;
  }
  ```

  No more pointers, no memory leaks, more performance and less code. If you must have pointers because you need polymorphic objects use a `unique_ptr`. It does what it says, it conceptually is the only pointer that points to that object, so if you have it you are the owner and if you throw it away the object disappears too. Obviously you cannot copy a `unique_ptr`, that would make it not unique anymore, this can be a problem. If you need to share values you can use `shared_ptr`, the last `shared_ptr` cleans up automatically. But those are already workarounds for special problems, stick to values as long as possible.
  I did not check in detail, but you can most likely change `vector<DirectedGraphNode*>` to `vector<DirectedGraphNode>` and greatly simplify the code. Same for the other containers.
- Prefer references over pointers. References unlike pointers always point to valid objects (unless you screwed up badly) and are easier to handle since you do not need to check for `nullptr` and can use regular syntax.

  ```
  T construct_path(unordered_map<DirectedGraphNode*, DirectedGraphNode* > *p_parents_f){
      u = (*p_parents_f)[u];
  }
  ```

  becomes more readable and easier to reason about:

  ```
  T construct_path(unordered_map<DirectedGraphNode*, DirectedGraphNode* > &p_parents_f){
      u = p_parents_f[u];
  }
  ```

  Obviously sometimes objects are optional and you need pointers to be able to express that, but don't make things unnecessarily complicated.
- The destructor of `PathFinder` is not `virtual`. If you inherit from it, let a base pointer point to a derived object and then `delete` the base pointer, the destructor of the derived class will not run making `PathFinder` not suitable as a base class. This will do it:

  ```
  class PathFinder{
      virtual ~PathFinder() = default;
  };
  ```
- Use name aliases for flexibility. At some point you may notice that an `unordered_set` is not a very good data structure to keep your `DirectedGraphNode`s in. A (sorted) `vector<DirectedGraphNode>` will most likely be much faster and use much less memory. If you wanted to switch you would have to change a lot of code. Instead you can used a name alias and `auto` to skip naming the type.

  ```
  class DirectedGraphNode {
  public:
      using Container = std::unordered_set<DirectedGraphNode>;
      Container m_in;
      Container m_out;
      typename Container::const_iterator begin();
  };

  ...

  auto start = myDirectedGraphNode.begin();
  ```

  Your IDE will probably tell you what type `start` is on mouseover, but ideally you don't actually care. It is some iterator type for some container, the rest is an unimportant implementation detail.
- The line `DirectedGraphNode* u = const_cast<DirectedGraphNode*>(touch);` is weird since `touch` is already a `DirectedGraphNode*`, making the cast useless. `auto u = touch;` would do the same thing.
- Some names could be improved. `touch` and `u` don't really tell me anything. I would expect `construct_path` to take a `const Container &graph`, a `const DirectedGraphNode &start` and a `const DirectedGraphNode &end`. Your code probably does basically that, but it is hard to see.

A few hints can make the difference between enjoying solving tricky problems in C++ and cursing a flood of segfaults, so feel free to show some improved code later and forgive the late reply.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will edit the code to reflect the suggested improvements shortly, yet I have to comment that, for instance, in `construct_path` I have used an "algorithmic idiom", i.e., I do not really need to ask for entire graph or the start node; a parent map and the last node of the path is everything we need to construct a shortest path.

Comment: @coderodde Be careful with editing the code. See [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765) first.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite good, but since you're a beginner like me, I have some advice that helps a lot in 2D-3D games.

- Try to use smart pointers, especially when you're dealing with tree-like data structures, like graph-node or some time it scene-node. If you want to make the memory management by yourself in tree data structure, make sure you have memory leak detection. Believe me, no matter how careful you are, some will behave unexpectedly throughout your code, risk will rise with tree data structure in particular.
- Try to make only needed member functions in classes, unless you make a library.
- Always make the code as simple as possible.